# Where does vaultQuery in RPC get its output from DB from in PersistentState

Tags: corda

Using the cordapp-example as a basis where the IOUstate is a queryableState and persisted. In the DB, you will see a new table IOU_States with column values as you have defined.

1. Build the project and start the nodes
2. Create a Tx from partyA to partyB

   flow start ExampleFlow iouValue: 50, otherParty: "O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US"
3. Run vaultquery() on partyA and take note of the displayed output (label as display 1)

   run vaultQuery contractStateType: com.example.state.IOUState
4. attach a H2 console to DB of partyA
5. Run search on IOU_States table
6. You will see the IOUState state object as a row item, note the value of 50
7. Run an update to change the value of 50 to 60
8. Run search on the IOU_States table to confirm the change
9. Run vaultquery() on partyA and take note of the displayed output (lable as display 2)
10. display 1 = display 2

Question:
1. When i have corrupted my persisted table, what exactly have i changed? 
2. Does vaultQuery() query the node_transactions instead and de-serialise from the blob?
3. In the Vault_states table, we used to have a column Contract_states, but it is no longer there. That is the snapshot we tend to change to test data tampering previously. Where is the snap shot of the state kept now?

Comment: IIRC, 1. during query corda is deserializing from the blob the jpa persisted table does not affect the data, 2,3. node_transaction just links to vault_states

Comment: Hahaha yeah trying to improve query performance.

Answer (score 0):

changing your state's table does not corrupt the transaction , the vault query acts on the vault, so even if you update the data , any transaction that has taken the manipulated state will not have inconsistencies

Comment: Well the point is that I am not trying to corrupt the transaction, but figuring out where the snapshot has gone. If vaultquery() which is to gather my state objects quickly, but if it keeps deserialising from the lo, then whats the point of having the persisted state. I might as well find a way to expose jpa to rpc so i can just read off the persisted table.